# What does this phrase mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> ‘One might get one’s Greek from the very lips of Homer and Plato,’ the
>   Very Young Man thought. ‘In which case they would certainly *plough
>   you for* the Little-go. The German scholars have improved Greek so
>   much.’

(From *The Time Machine* by H.G.Wells)

Answer (score 4):

According to the OED, [*to plough*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/plough) is to fail an examination; and Wikipedia says that the [*Little go*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsions) was an examination, actually called Responsions, that used to be required to obtain a degree at Oxford University. Then the sentence means that even if you learnt Greek from the ancient Greeks themselves you wouldn't pass a Greek exam in the late 19th century, because "the German scholars have improved Greek so much".
It looks like that was also asked and answered before at [wordreference](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=796942).